# How to iterate through a list and while iterating, iterate through another list and replace values for upper list with inner list key value pairs

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.5

Ok what i want is simple but i could not write it properly

I want to replace each value of a string list with multiple values (another list hold this values). I can write several loops however i want to execute it with a single line of command by using linq

`lstCrawlUrls` is a `List<string>`

`lstReplaceWordsFromUrls` is a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`

The below is not working as i am making a syntax error i need help to fix it thank you

```
lstCrawlUrls = lstCrawlUrls.Select(pr =>lstReplaceWordsFromUrls
                           .ForEach{mr =>( pr.Replace(mr.Key, mr.Value); }))
                           .ToList<string>();
```

c# .net 4.5

simple example

```
ListA (string list) = "home","work","play","swim"
listB (keyvalue pairs) = "me;aa","or;cc"
```

I replace values of ListA with listB so the listA becomes as below

```
"hoaa","wcck","play","swim"
```

Comment: That's some hard to read code for a one-liner, I'd go with a for loops. And the problem you have is because ForEach isn't returning a value.

Comment: @mot that is what i am asking. Omg i don't understand how some people still not able to this extremely clearly explained question understand and votes unclear

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: you're probably getting the downvote because you have the unreasonable constraint of requiring a one-liner, and also because you didn't post the compiler error and perhaps also because this really is a simple problem with loops that seasoned beginners should be able to handle. That's just my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on a one-liner, here's how to do it:

```
lstCrawlUrls = lstCrawlUrls.Select(pr => lstReplaceWordsFromUrls.Aggregate(pr, (str, mr) =>( str.Replace(mr.Key, mr.Value); )));
```